# How to implement the 'contain' spatial join in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How to select polygons which are contained in another polygon in Google Earth Engine? For example, in this case below, how to select only the red square completely within the green square, excluding the red square intersected?[image]

As far as I know, the functions, `.filterBounds()` or [the combination of `ee.Join.saveAll()` and `ee.Filter.withinDistance()`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/joins_spatial) , are utilized to conduct the spatial query of 'Intersection', not 'Contained'.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution: `ee.Filter.contains()` or `ee.Filter.isContained()`.

```
var polys = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-110.20732421875, 44.02023306138536],
                  [-110.20732421875, 43.464640103242],
                  [-109.3943359375, 43.464640103242],
                  [-109.3943359375, 44.02023306138536]]], null, false),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "0"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-108.84501953125, 43.480585732644144],
                  [-108.84501953125, 42.88779655005588],
                  [-107.944140625, 42.88779655005588],
                  [-107.944140625, 43.480585732644144]]], null, false),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "1"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-107.6365234375, 44.555012919342055],
                  [-107.6365234375, 43.941178353199525],
                  [-106.91142578125, 43.941178353199525],
                  [-106.91142578125, 44.555012919342055]]], null, false),
            {
              "landcover": 0,
              "system:index": "2"
            })]),
    givenGeometry= 
    /* color: #ffc82d */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[-110.55888671875, 45.22437812507874],
              [-110.55888671875, 42.32175585200791],
              [-107.30693359375, 42.32175585200791],
              [-107.30693359375, 45.22437812507874]]], null, false),
        {
          "id": 0,
          "system:index": "0"
        });

var containsFilter = ee.Filter.contains({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 1
});

// Define a saveAll join.
var distSaveAll = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'polygons',
});

// Apply the join.
var spatialJoined = distSaveAll.apply(givenGeometry, polys, containsFilter);
var listOfElements = spatialJoined.first().get('polygons')
var result = ee.FeatureCollection(listOfElements.getInfo());
print('result', result);
```

Comment: But the new issue is that the `.getInfo()` method may crash the browser if the listOfElements, which was fetched from server side, is too large.

Comment: You always have to cast objects obtained via `.get()`. Cast to an `ee.List()` and you don't need the `getInfo()`. [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff11b76be3ce62675be057af6a6fc63e)