# Calculating the intersection are of two featureCollections in Google Earth Engine using Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

A problem I'm trying to solve in Google Earth Engine. I would like to take two separate featureCollections and calculate the area of where they intersect. I'd like to do this in python, but just cant seem to get it working. My code so far:

```
# Select L2 administrative regions in Indonesia
gaul = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2")
indo_L2 = gaul.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', "Indonesia"))

# Global river basins
basins = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_8")

def nestedFCMapper(L2_fc, basins_fc):
    def mapL2AdminAreas(L2_f):
        def mapBasins(basin_f):
            intersection = basin_f.intersection(L2_f, ee.ErrorMargin(1))
            return ee.Feature(intersection).set('IntersectionArea', intersection.area())
        
        return basin_fc.map(mapBasins)
    
    return L2_fc.map(mapL2AdminAreas)

   
intersect_fc = nestedFCMapper(indo_L2,basins).filter(ee.Filter.gt('IntersectionArea',0))
intersect_fc.first().getInfo()
```

I tried to derive the answer from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365121/how-to-nest-mapped-functions-with-the-earth-engine-python-api), but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can this maybe help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363107/how-to-implement-the-contain-spatial-join-in-google-earth-engine